# no data appears on GA Ecommerce report

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I need your advice. My developer has implemented the enhanced e-commerce tracker to the website according to this guideline: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_purchases

The screenshot below is the screenshot of the data layer that fired when people reached the order completed page.
[image]

I'm tracking the order completion via the GTM event tag below:

[image]

This event is fired as expected on the order completed page, however, I'm not seeing the transaction data under the GA > eCommerce section after 2 days.

Do I need to advise the developer to implement the tag according to this guideline instead? https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

Is there anything I can do on my end without having the developer to amend the codes on their end?

I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're using GTM to pass enhanced ecommerce data you'll need it to be formatted as described in the GTM docs: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases so the pushed object has `ecommerce` property and subsequently the `purchase` property.

Your current setup will work with `gtag.js` implementation but **not with GTM Universal Analytics tag.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will ask the developer to try out the GTM guideline :)